# release memory opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv, memory-leaks

I already some post about releasing all the `IplImage` and all the `CvMat` structure and `CvMemStorage`, but still I have some memory problems.

Do I have to release also `CvPoint`, `CvScalar`, `CvPoint*` (array of 3 CvPoints, do i have to free each element too?)

If I have to release all this stuff, how do I? I did not find any function to do so. I'm using OpenCV 2.1 in C/C++.

Here is how I declare them:

```
CvScalar b1;
CvScalar f;
float *data=(float*)resd->imageData; (need to release data)
CvPoint *point;
CvPoint pt;
CvPoint* ptsCorner=(CvPoint*) malloc(3*sizeof(ptsCorner[0]));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is much more C related than OpenCV. For instance, these:

```
CvScalar b1;
CvScalar f;
CvPoint pt;
```

are local variables, and therefore they are automatically dealocatted when the scope `{ }` they belong finishes executing.

This:

```
CvPoint *point;
```

is a pointer, and at the same time is a local variable. You shouldn't `delete` or `free()` it because you didn't allocated any memory for it through `new` or `malloc()`. Doing so will cause you problems (probably a crash).

But `data` on the other hand:

```
float *data = (float*)resd->imageData;
```

is a pointer and local variable that holds a memory block. However, it's not wise to `delete[] data;` or `free(data)` in this specific case because you didn't allocate this memory directly. It's obvious that this memory was allocated as a part of `resd`, which means you have to check the code and find out how the variable `resd` was declared/initialized and then do the appropriate procedure to release it. Since I know a litle bit about OpenCV I can tell that `resd` is an `IplImage*`. If you used `cvCreateImage()` to create this variable then is also your job to release it with `cvReleaseImage()`.

At last:

```
CvPoint* ptsCorner=(CvPoint*) malloc(3*sizeof(ptsCorner[0]));
```

It's the tipical case of dynamic memory allocation, where you specifically allocate an amount  of memory. Since `ptsCorner` is a local variable and a pointer, when the scope it belongs to finishes executing you will loose the reference to that memory block and it will simply be lost in your RAM, caonsuming memory space and causing a leak. It's needless to say that you must execute `free()` to deallocate the memory in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are initializing the CVPoint structure using **new** then yes you will need to call **delete** (or **delete[]** if it's an array) to avoid leaking memory.

If not then when the function goes out of scope the variables will be automatically destroyed.

If you post your code then it will be easier to see.

Comment: add the declaration, all the code is very long, but I think is more clear now, btw I'm not using new so I guess I have to release just float *data (I try with delete but I get a runtime error) and *ptsCorner

Comment: Where you use malloc you will need to use free() to reclaim the memory. Be careful if it's an array as you need to call free() on each member of the array. Plenty of tutorials on how to do that out there

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve your problems is to read a good tutorial about pointers.

Here is one http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

What you say there are OpenCV problems, actually is a lack of understanding of programming languages. So, start with the basics, ad go on!